# Armadillo lapack linker error when using Visual Studio

Tags: linker-errors, curve-fitting, armadillo, lapack

The simple program below makes a call to polyfit to find the best line through the data points.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <armadillo>


using arma::vec;
using std::vector;

int main()
{
    vector <double> xcoords = { 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17 };
    vector <double> ycoords = { 32,35,29,34,30,24,32,24,23,28,21 };
    vec x = vec(xcoords);
    vec y = vec(ycoords);
    vec p = polyfit(x, y, 2);
}


`
```

``
The program compiles, but fails with 32 linker errors. They all appear to be related to lapack or blas. Now, the README seems to indicate that the precompiled library libopenblas.dll and libopenblas.lib contain BLAS and LAPACK, so I should have all the library code I need there. The compiler is Visual Studio C++ 2022 v143.

```
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sdot_ referenced in function "double __cdecl arma::blas::dot<double>(unsigned __int64,double const *,double const *)" (??$dot@N@blas@arma@@YAN_KPEBN1@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ddot_ referenced in function "double __cdecl arma::blas::dot<double>(unsigned __int64,double const *,double const *)" (??$dot@N@blas@arma@@YAN_KPEBN1@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sgemv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemv<double>(char const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemv@N@blas@arma@@YAXPEBDPEBH1PEBN21212PEAN1@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dgemv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemv<double>(char const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemv@N@blas@arma@@YAXPEBDPEBH1PEBN21212PEAN1@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cgemv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemv<double>(char const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemv@N@blas@arma@@YAXPEBDPEBH1PEBN21212PEAN1@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol zgemv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemv<double>(char const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemv@N@blas@arma@@YAXPEBDPEBH1PEBN21212PEAN1@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sgemm_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemm<double>(char const *,char const *,int const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemm@N@blas@arma@@YAXPEBD0PEBH11PEBN21212PEAN1@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dgemm_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemm<double>(char const *,char const *,int const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemm@N@blas@arma@@YAXPEBD0PEBH11PEBN21212PEAN1@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cgemm_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemm<double>(char const *,char const *,int const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemm@N@blas@arma@@YAXPEBD0PEBH11PEBN21212PEAN1@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol zgemm_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::gemm<double>(char const *,char const *,int const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$gemm@N@blas@arma@@YAXPEBD0PEBH11PEBN21212PEAN1@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ssyrk_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::syrk<double>(char const *,char const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$syrk@N@blas@arma@@YAXPEBD0PEBH1PEBN212PEAN1@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dsyrk_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::blas::syrk<double>(char const *,char const *,int const *,int const *,double const *,double const *,int const *,double const *,double *,int const *)" (??$syrk@N@blas@arma@@YAXPEBD0PEBH1PEBN212PEAN1@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sgeqrf_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::geqrf<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$geqrf@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH0PEAN01100@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dgeqrf_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::geqrf<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$geqrf@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH0PEAN01100@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cgeqrf_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::geqrf<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$geqrf@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH0PEAN01100@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol zgeqrf_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::geqrf<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$geqrf@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH0PEAN01100@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sorgqr_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::orgqr<double>(int *,int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$orgqr@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH00PEAN01100@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dorgqr_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::orgqr<double>(int *,int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$orgqr@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH00PEAN01100@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cungqr_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::ungqr<double>(int *,int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$ungqr@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH00PEAN01100@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol zungqr_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::ungqr<double>(int *,int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$ungqr@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH00PEAN01100@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sgesv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::gesv<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$gesv@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH0PEAN00100@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dgesv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::gesv<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$gesv@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH0PEAN00100@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cgesv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::gesv<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$gesv@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH0PEAN00100@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol zgesv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::gesv<double>(int *,int *,double *,int *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$gesv@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAH0PEAN00100@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sposv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::posv<double>(char *,int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$posv@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEADPEAH1PEAN1211@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dposv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::posv<double>(char *,int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$posv@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEADPEAH1PEAN1211@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cposv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::posv<double>(char *,int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$posv@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEADPEAH1PEAN1211@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol zposv_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::posv<double>(char *,int *,int *,double *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$posv@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEADPEAH1PEAN1211@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol strtrs_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::trtrs<double>(char *,char *,char *,int *,int *,double const *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$trtrs@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAD00PEAH1PEBN1PEAN11@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dtrtrs_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::trtrs<double>(char *,char *,char *,int *,int *,double const *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$trtrs@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAD00PEAH1PEBN1PEAN11@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ctrtrs_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::trtrs<double>(char *,char *,char *,int *,int *,double const *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$trtrs@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAD00PEAH1PEBN1PEAN11@Z)
1>pf3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ztrtrs_ referenced in function "void __cdecl arma::lapack::trtrs<double>(char *,char *,char *,int *,int *,double const *,int *,double *,int *,int *)" (??$trtrs@N@lapack@arma@@YAXPEAD00PEAH1PEBN1PEAN11@Z)
1>C:\Users\James\source\repos\pf3\x64\Debug\pf3.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 32 unresolved externals
```

Visual Studio 2022 in Windows 10 is set up with the following include and library declarations:

```
C:\armadillo-11.2.4\include
C:\armadillo-11.2.4\examples\lib_win64
```

Now, the puzzling thing is if I insert this same code in example1 which is a working Visual Studio project that calls most functions, the code works fine.
So that means that my little program is somehow not set up properly. The properties of example1 do not give me any clue, because everything is buried in a huge list of external dependencies.

What could I be doing wrong?

I tried to add the same external dependencies, but couldn't find them all. Surely there must be a more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are building using an x64 platform. In my case I was compiling/linking using (erroneously) an x86 platform.